# Plugin prevents code from working

Tags: plugins, rating

This is my blog http://animeii.tk/ (it might be down from time to time since the domain is still new)

The theme is Magazeen and I have this code there:

```
    <div class="dock-back container clearfix">

        <div class="latest"><h90>
            Check out the Latest Articles:
        </h90></div>

        <ul id="dock">
            <?php
                $dock = new WP_Query();
                $dock->query( 'showposts=9' );
                while( $dock->have_posts() ) : $dock->the_post();
            ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" >
                <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, "image_value", true ); ?>&amp;w=69&amp;h=54&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                </a>
                <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            </li>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            ?>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- End container -->

</div><!-- End latest-dock -->
```

Basically when hovering on a post - image , the "Check out the latest..." changes to the name of the post.

When the plugin WP-PostRatings is activated, the dock doesn't work on homepage. ONLY on post-pages and pages...

When I deactivate the plugin it's all working fine again...

Is there any other plugin for ratings that I can customize and put wherever I want it ?
Or is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these plugins:

- [GD Star Rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/)
- [WP Voting](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-voting/)

or if you don't mind spending a little then:

[Post Voting Plugin](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/post-voting-plugin)